# Missing csrf_token in application cookies

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, csrf-token

I have problem with setting my csrf_token in cookies which i have to retrieve in order to use it in the next API call
[Response header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CynD.png)
[Application cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jZdF.png)

CSRFToken.jsx

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const CSRFToken = () => {
  const [csrftoken, setcsrftoken] = useState('');

  const getCookie = (name) => {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== "") {
      let cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
      for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        let cookie = cookies[i].trim();
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === name + "=") {
          cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return cookieValue;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        await axios.get(`${import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_URL}/api/csrf_cookie`);
      } catch (error) {}
    };
    fetchData();
    setcsrftoken(getCookie('csrftoken') || "");
  }, []);

  return (
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value={csrftoken} />
  );
};

export default CSRFToken;
```

Backend:

```py
@method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie, name='dispatch')
class GetCSRFToken(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response({ 'success': 'CSRF cookie set' })
```

Any help provided will be much appreciated, thanks!

I should use csrftoken in API Call which i need to get from cookies, but they are not provided

```js
export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken')
        }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
```